# Traefik cert and route features

Tags: ssl, routes

We are working on a on-prim k8 cluster (No native Load Balancer like cloud )
and exploring traefik for SSL termination and routing. We have few questions
1) does it support more than 1 certs ( no wild card for us) , can we configure 1 cert per route ?
2) can we listen on low ports , 443 for all the ingress traffic to the cluster ? We plan front-end the nodes with a on-prim global load balancer.
3) does all ingress configuration needs to be in ONE yaml ? can can we split configurations(route and ssl info) per application
4) We are using istio for east-west traffic , any issues with integration ?

Answer (score 0):

Got response from @nicomengin

I hope these responses will help you:

> 1) does it support more than 1 certs ( no wild card for us),
>   Yes you can define many services per entrypoints statically (in the Traefik configuration) or dynamically (thanks to the TLS secrets in K8s)
>
> can we configure 1 cert per route ?
>   The certificates are linked to entrypoints. As you can define many certificates per entrypoints, you can define a certificate for each (sub) domains. So, I'll say yes you can do that.
>
> 2) can we listen on low ports , 443 for all the ingress traffic to the cluster ? We plan front-end the nodes with a on-prim global load balancer.
>   Yes, you can define entrypoints on all the ports you need, then you can define if they are TLS or not
>
> 3) does all ingress configuration needs to be in ONE yaml ? can can we split configurations(route and ssl info) per application
>   Yes you can split your ingress rules in many YAML files
>
> 4) We are using istio for east-west traffic , any issues with integration ?
>   No issues you can use together Traefik for nourth-south and Istio for esat-west